# Expect an element by xpath to have specific text

Tags: xpath, protractor

After pressing a save button a box will pop up and say if it was success or failed. The box has the same xpath no matter the result.

```
expect(element(by.xpath('path example')));
```

Inside the HTML for the element it says

```
<div class="panc lm-he" style="....."><span style="..."> Saved!</span></div>
```

edit -- oops it's early.

I want to know how can I have the expect come back true if the text "Saved!" is there or not. So if "Saved!" is present inside that element then it's true otherwise it's false.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to have an expect statement that looks by xpath and by the text "Saved!"

Comment: did you research the problem?  it is a widely documented use case, both here and on the protractor API

Comment: I did, but it always says use something other than xpath, which I'm not very good at. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api doesn't make too much sense to me on their documentation I think im just better at learning through examples than text.

Comment: Just because the examples dont use xpath doesnt mean you cant use them.  all locators in protractor return the same object, an [ElementFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) or an [ElementArrayFinder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder).  I would start there

Answer (score 0):

Try with showing the output of the entire element like this:

```
element(by.xpath('path example')).then(function(element){
    console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand want you want, but this way you will check if div with 'Saved!' text is Displayed

```
expect(element(by.xpath('.//div[text(), "Saved!"]')).isDisplayed).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Gunderson notes it doesn't matter what locator you use, the syntax will be the same.  When I want to confirm text in an element I usually do something like this:

```
myElement.getText().then(function (text) {
        expect(text).toContain(message)
    });
```

That way you can tell by looking at the failure if the element didn't show up at all, or if it is visible but the text is not displayed, or if everything is fine and the test passes.  So in your case it would just be

```
element(by.xpath('path example')).getText().then(function (text) {
        expect(text).toContain('Saved!')
    });
```